# Internet Explorer 8 doesn't apply display inline and block correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

In short.
I have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .vertical_panel > .fields > .item {
        display: block;
        background-color: #344;
    }

    .horizontal_panel > .fields > .item {
        display: inline;
        background-color: #FAE;
    }

    .item {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 2px;
    }

    .fields {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #specialSpan {
        display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;   
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div  class="horizontal_panel" id = "specialSpan" style="width: 300px; height: auto;">
    <fieldset class="fields">
        <span class="vertical_panel item" style="width: 300px; height: auto;">
            <fieldset class="fields">
                <div class="item">
                    <span>text</span>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <span>text</span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </span>

        <div class="item">
            <span>text</span>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <span>text</span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's an approximation to my code structure. There are more elements inside the fields. So, I have a javascript function which toggles class of panels.

The problem is: I have correct selectors, correct values of style are set(display), but Internet Explorer 8 does not apply it correctly. The items does not change their direction if I call that function. Under “does not change direction” I mean that items does no rendered as `display: block` or `display: inline`.

There is a key part: if I open debug tools and enter `display: inline` for instance manually for panels, almost everything looks fine. But if I have correct view before manual style changes and I have changed the style, I can't change view back to normal in ordinary way — with call of function.

The function is something like:

```
function SetPanelOrientation(panel) {
    // this attribute doesn't exit in example but actually exist in project's code
    // and always correct
    var isVertical = panel.getAttribute("IsVertical");
    if (isVertical == '0') {
        $(panel)
            .removeClass('vertical_panel')
            .addClass('horizontal_panel');
    } else {
        $(panel)
            .removeClass('horizontal_panel')
            .addClass('vertical_panel');
    }
};
```

I can see in debugger tools that class changed, but view doesn't change. I've tried many combinations with `block` and `inline-block` but have not found working combination.

Comment: instead of working on html 4 transitional, try working on html 5
instead of using internet explorer 8, use other browsers.
It's no more the developer's task to keep everything compatible. Users have internet around the world so the best is to advise them to download the latest browser versions, or forget about IE.

REgards

Comment: @ARMBouhali I can't change to modern technologies because of technical reasons.

Comment: @ARMBouhali: You do realize you're talking to the developer and not the users...

Comment: @ARMBouhali do you realize that there are projects with several millions of lines of code and just change of doctype will cause unimaginable amount of bugs and refactoring?

Comment: Please state explicitly what the problem is. “Does not render it correctly” is not a problem description, and “The items does not change their direction if I push a button and call that function” does not really make it clear. Which items? How should they arrange and why? Which button? Which function? You show a function, but it is not called anywhere. And there is no button in the code. Maybe something to be styled and scripted to act as a button.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela item is object with class .item. I thought it clear. Button doesn't really relevant. Function is in the code. Well, yeah, it's not called, but I can't make short example of code that doesn't work, only some approximation of it. So, I can't reproduce the bug outside of project's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing in doctype, nor in property values. Set styles with jquery instead of css file helps.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the doctype you are using, you are in quirks mode, and IE will perform as if it were 1998 all over again. New web pages should not be using that doctype since 1999.

The only way around this is to set the element's CSS properties to how you want them to be versus how other browsers are correctly displaying them.

Comment: While this is probably all true, it does not answer the question asked. (Well, I think it is a non-answer to a non-question.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I thought I was just tired but you might be right cause I don't think I was totally clear what the question was.

Comment: Browsing of internet shows that there is no problems with display property. Unfortunately, I can't give correctly not working example, because it doesn't work only in my environment. I can't past several 1k lines files here. With new doctype, I have another issues. And that's why I can't switch.

Comment: Fun fact which nobody take into account: when I enter values through debug tools, exactly as values that are already in the styles, letter to letter, it looks like it should look.

Comment: @cassandradied You are correct and I removed that from my answer. The reason changing the doctype changes everything else is because the other stuff was created in quirks mode and, with the new doctype, you would be in standards mode where you should be. That's why new web pages should always use a standards mode doctype and you never want to be in quirks.